# How to make filled out buttons in React Native

Tags: react-native

When I make buttons on React Native and use the Expo app on Iphone, the buttons render as only text. I need the buttons to fully render with a colored background and border radius etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add styles to the button. This is a good example provided by expo:[Expo Button styles](https://docs.expo.dev/ui-programming/react-native-styling-buttons/)

```
    //You can also add a height and width to the styles
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("pressed")} 
                style={{backgroundColor: 'tomato', padding: 15, borderRadius:10}}>
        <Text>Press Me!</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```